# Strcpy does not copy an allocated character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

Why does this not work:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(char *lit) //Ctor
{
    str = new char[strlen(lit)+1]; // str is a pointer to char in SomeClass
    strcpy(str,"have");
    cout << str << " " << "In Ctor" << " +Size=" << strlen(str)<< endl;
}
```

The above code shows a string with length 0. But this code works:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(char *lit)
{
    char newstr[strlen(lit)+1];
    strcpy(newstr,"have");
    cout << newstr << " " << "In Ctor" << " +Size=" << strlen(newstr)<< endl;
}
```

**[Here](http://ideone.com/MBctI)** is the complete code.

EDIT:
Added the link to Ideone which OP removed after I answered the Question.
Without the link to source code, this Q & answer to it is useless.

Comment: Please produce a **complete**, **short** program that demonstrates the error you are seeing. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: In both cases, you're sizing the array to the length of the passed-in string `lit`. What guarantee is there that `lit` is at least four characters long?

Comment: @amit: No they are not allowed by the standard, but there are compiler extensions which provide that functionality.

Comment: I am not a c++ expert. I know c99 has variable length arrays. I have no idea if C++ has it as well. If not - that might be the issue. [sorry for mistakenly deleting and reposting the comment, @Als's comment seems out of context now, though it certainly isn't]

Comment: @amit: No, C++ does not have VLAs, though some compilers (e.g., gcc) include them as an extension. On an unrelated note, is there a good reason to go through all these gyrations instead of just using `std::string`?

Comment: Code is useless w/o information what do you pass in `lit`.

Comment: Here is the Full Code - this is what i am trying: http://ideone.com/iQZzf

Comment: Please use your copy and paste tools to post the actual program output and/or error message instead of "does not work".

Comment: @JerryCoffin sir i am newbie, and if don't do such programs how will i learn?

Comment: @Lohit: "For learning" is a perfection good reason -- I just wanted to make sure you weren't writing this for production code because you thought you needed to, or something on that order.

Comment: Why have you removed the link to the source code? Without it the Q and answer is useless for anyone who faces similar problem in future.Please edit it back to the Q!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with the `strcpy`, You are just messing your pointer.

The problem is here:

```
 str = new char[strlen(lit)+1];
 strcpy(str,lit);
 length=leng();    <------------- str points to \0 after this call
 cout << str << " " << "In Ctor" << " +Size=" << strlen(lit)<< endl;
```

`str` is your class member and You move the pointer `str` to point to the `\0` in the function `leng()`, Naturally, You don't see any output in the next statement.

Solution is to hold the starting address in a separate pointer inside the function.

```
int String :: leng()
{
      int length=0;
      char *tempPtr= str;       <----------- Store the address in a temporary pointer
      while(*str)
      {
                 length++;
                 str++;
      }
      str = tempPtr;            <---------- Point the Pointer member to right address again
      return length;
}
```

Comment: In addition, make `String::leng()` method `const`, so the constraint of not modifying class state (including `str` data member) is more evident.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write `String::leng()`:

```
int String::leng()
{
    char *endPtr = str;
    while(*endPtr)
        endPtr++;
    return endPtr - str;
}
```